# Swift MKMapView.setRegion not working after MKLocalSearch.Request

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swiftui

I've been working on an app to annotate an MKMapView with all nightlife locations near a user. I have implemented a recenter function that is called by a SwiftUI button. The recenter works fine based on CLLocationManager.location, but after any MKLocalSearch query, the setRegion stops working. It must be the setRegion because the correct lat/long are still printed. I also know it is not due to the annotations because the same bug happens when the annotation add/remove part is commented out. Does it possibly have something to do with linking the searchRequest.region and map.region? `manager` is the CLLocationManager instance, `map` is the MapView

```
func recenter(){
        print("Recenter called")
        guard let center = manager.location?.coordinate else{
            print("Could not get location for recenter")
            return
        }
        let newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
        print("\(center.latitude) and \(center.longitude)")
        map.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)
    }
```

```
func queryAndAnnotate(){
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "nightlife"
        searchRequest.region = map.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
        search.start{response, error in
            guard let response = response else {
                Alert(title:Text("Alert"), message: Text("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription  ?? "Unknown Error")"))
                return
            }
            var mapItemPlacemarks: [MKPointAnnotation] = []
            self.barsList = []
            for i in response.mapItems{
                let x = MKPointAnnotation()
                x.coordinate = i.placemark.coordinate
                x.title = i.name
                mapItemPlacemarks.append(x)
            }
            self.map.removeAnnotations(mapItemPlacemarks)
            self.map.addAnnotations(mapItemPlacemarks)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`MKLocalSearch.start` calls the completionHandler in background task.

In this handler you are updating your mapView instance in background task.

Make sure to call all update methods of mapView in main task (`removeAnnotations`, `addAnnotations`, `setRegion`)

btw in

```
self.map.removeAnnotations(mapItemPlacemarks)
self.map.addAnnotations(mapItemPlacemarks)
```

you are removing mapItemPlacemarks that do not exist in the mapView. This makes no sense, but it is not your problem.

Comment: Tried but no change in outcome. It turns out the problem actually occurs from adding the found places to an array that is represented in a ScrollView that is displayed over the map in slide up drawer. I suspect the mapview thinks it is no longer visible and thus resets itself. I will re ask the question with this new information

Comment: Ok. Make updates in the main task nevertheless, it will prevent other problems.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem was coming from a dynamic update to a ScrollView. The ScrollView was within a slide up drawer that sat above the MapView on the Z axis. When the ScrollView was updated with the results from the local search, the MapView object lost track of userLocation (read 0,0) and the region could not be programmatically changed. I ended up fixing the problem by ditching the recenter() function altogether and instead implementing an MKUserTrackingButton within its own UIViewRepresentable (for SwiftUI). The MKUserTrackingButton is how the system maps cycles through user tracking modes. You can read the docs for it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingbutton

Comment: Could you post an example on how you enabled the interaction of the `MKUserTrackingButton` with the `MKMapView` through SwiftUI?